# Type Casting Exception With Inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, casting

Here is my code below. It gives me Casting exception problem at selIngs.Add(da). tried with the 2nd way. it still give me the same exception. I wonder where I am doing wrong? Once I implement the interface or inherit the base class it should be ok to treat child class as the same. Any idea please?

```
//1st way
public interface IngredientInterface
{
    double Concentration { get; set; }
    string DateCreated { get; set; }
    string DevCode { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientData : INotifyPropertyChanged, IngredientInterface
{
      public string GroupCode
    {
        get { return groupCode; }
        set
        {
            groupCode = value;
        }
    }
    public double Setpoint { get; set; }

    public bool IsHighlighted { get; set; }

    public double PPT { get; set; }
}

public class FormulaUploadViewModelData: IngredientData
{
    //.....
}

public class FormulaUploadViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public FormulaUploadViewModel()
    {
        selIngs = new List<FormulaUploadViewModelData>();
    }

    private void IngsUp()
    {   
        List<IngredientData> someIngData = new List<IngredientData>();
         foreach (FormulaUploadViewModelData da in someIngData)
         {
                selIngs.Add(da); //here gives me casting exception
         }
    }
}

//2nd way
public class FormulaUploadViewModelData: IngredientInterface
{
    //.....
}

public class FormulaUploadViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public FormulaUploadViewModel()
    {
        selIngs = new List<FormulaUploadViewModelData>();
    }

    private void IngsUp()
    {   
         List<IngredientInterface> someIngData = new List<IngredientInterface>();
         foreach (FormulaUploadViewModelData da in someIngData)
         {
                selIngs.Add(da); //here gives me casting exception
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var da in someIngData.OfType<FormulaUploadViewModelData>())` should work. It gives you all elements of the source collection that actually are of the derived type.

Answer (score 0):

All `FormulaUploadViewModelData` are `IngredientInterface`. So this will work:

```
var ingredients = new List<IngredientInterface>();
ingredients.Add(new FormulaUploadViewModelData());
```

But the opposite does not work because not all `IngredientInterface` are `FormulaUploadViewModelData` which is what should follow from allowing:

```
var formulas = new 
    List<FormulaUploadViewModelData>();
formulas(someIngredientInterface);
```

Solution? Make sure the `da` you are adding is in fact a `FormulaUploadViewModelData`. There is quite a few ways to do it, to name a couple:

- Pattern matching

  ```
  foreach (var da in someInData)
      if (da is FormulaUploadViewModelData formula)
          selIngs.Add(formula)
  ```
- Use `Enumerable.OfType<>` extension method

  ```
  foreach (var formula in
      someInData.OfType<FormulaUploadViewModelData>())
      selIngs.Add(formula)
  ```
- Etc.